# Accuracy of nema17 versus nema23 1.8 degree step

Tags: stepper-motor

I am trying to decide on using a nema17 or nema23 for my 3d printer.  I have already considered torque, but step accuracy is very important.  I wouldn't mind moving the bed plate up and down much slower with a nema 17 if it was more accurate.

It seems that 5% accuracy on a 1.8 degree step is the benchmark.  But can anyone offer some insight into which is typically more accurate or if they are the same.

Comment: Are you using a lead screw for the Z motion? If so 5% of 1.8° on a lead screw seems very small and the error would be small compared to other mechanical problems. What is your intended setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, it makes no difference whether you use NEMA 17 or NEMA 23 providing both supply enough torque to move your bed plate.
You need to define your need for both resolution and accuracy to make any real suggestions. If your need is a simple DIY 3D printer, then the comments below might help you.

Consider moving to a 0.9 degree stepper motor if you want better resolution using a fixed microstep setting. Microstepping is your Achilles Heel in getting good open loop positioning performance, you want to minimize it at all costs.

In a bed positioning role your number of steps/second is low, your major factors are step resolution and torque. Compare these two 1.8d [NEMA 17/23](https://pages.pbclinear.com/rs/909-BFY-775/images/Data-Sheet-Stepper-Motor-Support.pdf) steppers to a 0.9d M[oons stepper range](https://www.moonsindustries.com/c/hybrid-stepper-motors-a0201/stepangle-0.9%C2%B0). The 0.9d is still 5% step accuracy.

You could also consider using a geared stepper motor and reducing the microsteps, but at the accuracy extremes you'd need to make sure you always travel in one direction from a home position (this can work well for bed positioning).

If you truly are looking for higher accuracy (and not just resolution), you need to consider a closed loop positioning solution. You could do no better than change to a [Clearpath](https://www.teknic.com/model-info/CPM-SDSK-2310D-RLN/?model_voltage=75VDC) servo to provide the best possible solution if your driver is Pulse/Direction.